# How do I set RAILS_ENV to 'Production' on a DreamHost shared server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, dreamhost

I have a shared server running passenger to server my Rails app. For some reason my RAILS_ENV variable seems to be stuck as 'Development'. How do I set it to 'Production'? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a shared hosting environment, you will want to do this in a `.htaccess` file, placed inside `public/`. Mine looks like this:

```
PassengerEnabled on
PassengerAppRoot /home/myuser/myapp/current
RailsEnv production
```

Comment: You may also need `RackEnv production` for Rails 3.

Comment: My folder structure is as so /home/user/domain/myapp/public
Would I create the .htaccess file inside that public folder? Note: I have not yet set up capistrano to deploy the app.

Comment: Yes, inside that public folder.

Comment: `RailsEnv production` was what I was looking for.